# Chrome says my extension's manifest file is missing or unreadable

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm a new chrome extension developer, and I was going through the Chrome tutorial on making a "Hello World" extension, here's my code:

```
     {
      "name": "My First Extension",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "description": "The first extension that I made.",
      "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": "icon.png"
      },
       "permissions": [
       "http://api.flickr.com/"
      ]
      }
```

When I went to load the unpacked extension it said the manifest file was missing or unreadable. Yes I have the image in a folder with it and it is correctly named manifest.json

Comment: This looks correct. Perhaps try and just recreate the file?

Comment: I'm a dummy. Note to anyone else who runs into this while trying to pack an unpacked developery extension they just unzipped from source: make sure you're pointing Chrome to the folder with files directly in it, and not to the folder with *another* folder with files in it, because your unzipping program was trying to be helpful, drr.

Comment: --load-extension=%windri%\extension_dev <----- load dir not a crx file !!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Something that commonly happens is that the manifest file isn't named properly.  Double check the name (and extension) and be sure that it doesn't end with *.txt* (for example).

In order to determine this, make sure you aren't hiding file extensions:

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Go to Folder and Search Options > View tab
3. Uncheck *Hide extensions for known file types*

Also, note that the naming of the manifest file is, in fact, case sensitive, i.e. *manifest.json* != *MANIFEST.JSON*.

Comment: My problem was with not pointing exactly to manifest file because accepted answer does not mention it. I also thought that Chrome scans subdirectory for manfest file.

Answer (score 19):

My problem was slightly different.

By default Eclipse saved my manifest.json as an ANSI encoded text file.

Solution:

- Open in Notepad
- File -> Save As
- select UTF-8 from the encoding drop-down in the bottom left.
- Save

Comment: Thanks!  That was my problem too - the extension would load on Mac Chrome but not on Windows Chrome because of the manifest encoding.

Answer (score 11):

I also encountered this issue.

My problem was that I renamed the folder my extension was in, so all I had to do was delete and reload the extension.

Thought this might help some people out there.

Comment: where did you delete and reload the extension from?

Comment: i was able to do it with this solution

Answer (score 6):

Mine also was funny. While copypasting " manifest.json" from the tutorial, i also managed to copy a leading space. Couldn't get why it's not finding it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are downloading samples from developer.chrome.com its possible that your actual folder is contained in a folder with the same name and this is creating a problem. For example your extracted sample extension named tabCapture will lool like this:

```
C:\Users\...\tabCapture\tabCapture
```

Answer (score 1):

Some permissions issue for default sample.

I wanted to see how it works, I am creating the first extension, so I downloaded a simpler one.

Downloaded 'Typed URL History' sample from
    https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/history/showHistory.zip

which can be found at
    https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples

this worked great, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

On Linux (fedora) I was able to solve the problem by changing the path to the folder.

By default, it selected `~/path-to-folder`
I thus forced it to use `/home/user/path-to-folder`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check whether you have installed right version of ChromeDriver or not . In my case  , installing correct version helped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the problem of building the extension, I was pointing at an extension src (with manifest and everything) but without a build.

If you run into this scenario run
`npm i`
then
`npm build`

Answer (score 0):

Kind of dumb: But make sure manifest.json is not spelled mainifest.json.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting for me the issue was that I copied from https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/

and I saved it with

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "A plain text description"
}
```

Once i removed default_locale it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to using the wrong path on one of the servers that was saved as an environmental variable. So manifest file was in fact missing there.