# Chrome cannot read my manifest file (extension making)

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

## Description

So I recently decided to try to make a chrome extension.
So following this tutorial https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted
I made a `manifest.json` file
with the following code:

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Following the instructions to

> Click the LOAD UNPACKED button and select the extension directory.

## Problem

I attempt to load the extension and get the error
`Manifest file is missing or unreadable`

## What I've tried

So before you mark this duplicate, I have read:
[Chrome says my extension's manifest file is missing or unreadable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533661/chrome-says-my-extensions-manifest-file-is-missing-or-unreadable)

and I have tried the answers, my manifest file is **INDEED** a `.json` file.
I have made a new folder and remade my extension.
I have checked to see if the `json` was valid (it is).

My manifest file is stored at `Users\...\phpstormprojects\extension\manifest.json`
I am attempting to upload the `extension` folder.

**Note:** I have tried zipping the folder and uploading it and it as well hasn't worked.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. To make sure it is, I need to look at the actual manifest.json file so please zip it (this is important) and upload to any file hosting e.g. Google drive or dropbox.

Comment: Heres the uploaded .zip folder.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h_9iY4RGi1L6sKdMWtGpEdX5SXPCBi09

Answer (score 1):

it happened to me also then i downloaded the example manifest from here

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/tutorials/get_started/manifest.json

put it on the wanted directory
and changed the content to my content- it works!