# ERROR: [Radix Wallet Chrome Extension Load Unpack] : Manifest file is missing or unreadable. Could not load manifest

Tags: scrypto

I am trying to follow the babylon gumball machine https://github.com/radixdlt/babylon-alphanet/tree/main/gumball-machine-example

I tried to install Radix Wallet Chrome Extension from :
https://docs.radixdlt.com/main/scrypto/alphanet/wallet-extension.html

I am getting following error :
Manifest file is missing or unreadable. Could not load manifest.
[image]

I tried to search for *manifest.json* , but I was not able to find it anywhere and in any sub-directory.
[image]
I tried to follow this stackoverflow : [Chrome says my extension's manifest file is missing or unreadable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533661/chrome-says-my-extensions-manifest-file-is-missing-or-unreadable)

Can I get some help/guidance for resolving this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 12/11/2022, the latest release for the alphanet wallet is `0.1.1` and the `0.1.5` release states there are no changes to the wallet so you just need to download the latest release with `alphanet-walletextension-vX.X.X.zip`, in this case:

[alphanet-walletextension-v0.1.1.zip](https://github.com/radixdlt/babylon-alphanet/releases/download/v0.1.1/alphanet-walletextension-v0.1.1.zip)